# manage drawing entities Inside Forge ambience

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

i am using VB6 using the autocad API. 
is it possible to move insert rotate blocks with the autodesk-designautomation api?
Also extract block attributes and change them?
Create new drawings changing DWG block attributes and save them?

if yes. How?

Best Regards

Luis

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry, VB6 is not supported in Forge Design Automation. You'll have to use VB.NET (define an autocad command).

Comment: Hi Luis, this is some materials on how to migrate VB to VB.NET of AutoCAD: http://www.autodesk.com/vba  and a video course: DevTV: AutoCAD VBA to VB.NET Migration Basics.  Please let us know if there is any question when you migrating.